# Move website by switching drive letters

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, migration, mappeddrive

I want to move all website data from one drive to another as the storage is almost full. As I also want to keep the drive letter to the website drive I thought of switching the drive letters in windows to move to the new drive. Here is what I thought to to:
1. Stop IIS 6 and all services accessing the original drive.
2. Copy all files including NTFS rights to the new drive
3. Switch the drive letters of the two drives
4. Start IIS again

All without reboot. Would this be possible? Is changing the drive letter sufficient or are there any constraints in the background that would not be updated? I assume with this method I would not have to change any configuration etc.

Comment: Is your website on the same drive where IIS6 is installed?

Comment: No IIS is on drive c: (default install) and the website is on another website-dedicated drive.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just clone the smaller drive to the larger drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work without problems. IIS uses filesystem paths in its configuration, it doesn't care at all about low-level disk details.

Comment: IIS does not care but, for ex., other components, framework, services, servers, dll dependencies (in chain), on which depend/build website do

Comment: @vgv8, none of those care about which partition/volume/disk they reside on; the full path is all that is need to reference them.

Comment: it was hard to get rid of all processes accessing the drive, but finally it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I think in all scenarios, it would be more proper, more smooth and more versatile [to mount new partition/disk-drive as folder](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1681&page=27) on the old drive first. This does not constrain you to change it any time later on how you would wish

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work.

Make sure that it's working before you delete anything, and backup, backup, backup!